# Wrong Object Returned From Reference

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Does anyone know why code within the object literal the "@" (this) references the enclosing object rather than the immediate?

```
class Example extends Backbone.View
  render: ->
    test =
      num: 10
      nextNum: @num + 1 # References "Example" not "test"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a Hash constructor, and sending params to the constructor. I see this code similar (maybe no the same) to this one:

```
var test = new Hash({ num: 10, nextNum: this.num + 1 });
```

I think in the above example you can see clearly that `this` is making reference to the outer object and not to the `test` instance itself, among other things because the `test` instance is still not created.

In the example above you would resolve the issue like this:

```
var num = 10;
var test = new Hash({ num: num, nextNum: num + 1 });
```

So moving this to your case I think you should solve it in a similar way:

```
class Example extends Backbone.View
  render: ->
    num = 10

    test =
      num: num
      nextNum: num + 1
```